# Camel ActiveMQ: Consuming messages based on the JMSTimestamp

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have defined a  `Route` which consumes messages from a queue without any problems, and right now I am trying to consume the messages that have been in the queue for 12 hours, I got the idea to use a `selector`, but no idea how to use it with `JMSTimestamp` to meet the 12 hours criteria.

This is the `Route`:

```
<route id="INBOUND.RECEIVE.IN">
    <from
        uri="activemq:queue:QXL.INBOUND.RECEIVE.IN?selector=JMSTimestamp%3D${date.time}&amp;concurrentConsumers=10&amp;destination.consumer.prefetchSize=0&amp;deliveryPersistent=true&amp;username=admin01&amp;password=001!admin01001!" />
    <pipeline>
        <bean method="inboundReceive" ref="logipalServices"/>
    </pipeline>
</route>
```

And this is the date bean

```
    <bean id="date" class="java.util.Date"  scope="prototype"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation, **I think something is wrong with your selector**.

`JMSTimestamp%3D${date.time}` means `JMSTimestamp = ${date.time}`

It means you're looking for all messages with the **exact** `JMSTimestamp`. Since [**`Date.getTime()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) returns time in milliseconds, it's very unlikely, you will retrieve any message from the queue.

I think you should try something like :

```
JMSTimestamp > current date - 12 hours (pseudo code for selector)
```

I hope this will help you.